# How to prevent the repeated values in table of iReport-3.6.7?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to create a report using iReport-3.6.7 IDE. I've added a dataset which I used for filling the values into a Table in the report's Details section. Everything is fine with the report compilation. But problem is that when I run the report in the IDE, it displays entire values as much is the number of tuples in the source table. i.e. if my table in source database has 16 tuples, then in iRepoort IDE the table is repeated 16 times. Please, don't tell me I'd place it in other sections e.g. Table Header, Table Footer, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused due to my bad approach to report design. Since everything we put into the Detail band of iReport gets populated at run-time, my table (which I'd put in Detail band of report) got populated as many times as of the tuple returned by the report's query.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fix it, editing the query SQL in the subreport 1 in the header space, ande the supreport2 in the detail space, if your table is large and you put in the header space , then will give you an error like this "infinite loop creating new page due to column header overflow"

Answer (score 0):

make false "print Repeated value" By Selecting particular Field